# logback - is there a way to include all config files from directory

Tags: java, logback

Is there a way to do something along the lines:

```xml
<configuration>
  <include file="src/main/java/chapters/configuration/*.xml" />
<!-- some common stuff -->
</configuration>
```

Note `*.xml` in `<include>` tag. I have an application consisting of 9 modules, but not all of them are always present. In addition there are external modules that can be installed optionally and I don't know their names in advance (by `names` I mean class names or config names) or how they should be configured. If there was a way to include files using wildcard I could simply notify developers that they should place their config files in some directory (e.g. `config/logging/`) and I'd be set for life. Currently files must be included by hand. Of course I could write some code that monitors given file for new configurations and include them programmatically in main configuration file (or proper `<include>` tags), but maybe there is already a way to do it.

Comment: Regarding to the [logback documentation](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#fileInclusion) I guess it is not possible. But I think you can create a little script to add the inclusion files before you want to use your configuration file.

Comment: Yup, AFAIK this isexactly as you described. I want everything to happen automagically, so problem with little script is that it must be somehow executed, so I need runtime for this language, so something working well with Java is preferred, so probably Groovy or something similar, and even then I have to schedule it and restart whole application after mangling configuration xml file... It becomes a project in itself, that's why I wanted to know if it is possible to do it without additional changes :/